# Running PowerShell scripts programmatically in Azure Web Sites

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service

I want to run PS scripts in C# exactly along the lines of [Sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/08/29/mvps-for-exchange-online-calling-exchange-online-powershell-cmdlets-from-c.aspx)

This works on a Cloud Service (Web Role), on a standard server (with execution policy disabled), but not in a Azure Web Site.

Anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any official documentation on the issue but there are multiple answers on the [related forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads) where Microsoft employees talk about the limitations of not being able/allowed to launch external processes in Windows Azure Web Sites. See

- [PHP - Warning: exec(): Unable to fork](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/c868b2f6-b604-4cf9-bf54-cacad06c881b)
- [PDF Generator failing on Azure Website but not development machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/5b51ec05-da97-4ea8-a495-98d45224cde4)
- [Recommended HTML to PDF Generator that works on Azure Website Reserved mode with Full Trust](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/939df0a0-30c9-4a5d-a44c-95765e1a4db7)

You are probably trying to do that with your powershell script.

You could verify if that is in fact your issue by catching and looking at the exception(s) which should relate to security policies/permissions.